# Garbled 2D textures/sprites in N64 cartridge

Tags: nintendo-64

I'm experiencing a weird problem with one of my N64 carts. The game boots fine, but the graphics are garbled. Music is fine, game logic is fine (I can press "start" enough times and actually get into the gameplay). The cartridge PCB looks OK just from a visual inspection. Any ideas what problem this is, and how to fix?

[image: garbled sprites from game intro]
[image: fuzzy/blurry game title screen]
[image: gameplay screen with missing main character, offset sprites]

Comment: Sounds like the cartridge PCB is not in fact okay. You should post a picture of the cartridge. The fine folks at https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ might have better experience with this sort of thing. FWIW, it pains me to say that the N64 is considered retro :'(